# .Net 1.1 url rewrite on iis 7

Tags: url, iis-7, url-rewriting, asp.net-1.1

We have old aspx application written in .NET 1.1 with url rewrite (wildcard) on IIS 6.0 
and I need to upgrade to IIS 7.

App is now working on IIS 7.0  but without url rewrite.

I tried this example:

> http://improve.dk/blog/2006/12/11/making-url-rewriting-on-iis7-work-like-iis6

but this example is for .NET 2.0 and these steps change `web.config` with elements not permitted in ASP.NET 1.1.

Is there any way configure IIS 7.0 for .NET 1.1 app without changing the source code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming that you've installed .NET 1.1 on your server and that your application is running inside an application pool configured to use .NET Framework 1.1 as per this article:

> [How to install ASP.NET 1.1 with IIS7 on Vista and Windows 2008](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/06/02/installing-asp-net-1-1-with-iis7-on-vista-and-windows-2008.aspx)

If you are then try adding the following to your `web.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
  <handlers>
   <add name="ASP.NET-ISAPI-1.1-Wildcard" 
        path="*" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" 
        scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\aspnet_isapi.dll" 
        resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" 
        preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv1.1,bitness32" />
        </handlers>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you linked to my blog in your post, I'll allow myself to link to a newer version of that post (which is also linked to in the original post):
http://improve.dk/archive/2009/10/14/how-to-do-url-rewriting-on-iis-7-properly.aspx

You should be able to use the "Rewriting using an HttpModule" method to add URL Rewriting to your app without modifying your existing code.